# Modificar contenido HTML recuperado con Kotlin

Tags: html, android, kotlin

```
`

    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    var datas = arrayOf(String())
    val textBox = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView1)

        Thread(Runnable {
            try {
                val url = URL("https://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html")
                val con = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                var contador: Int = 0
                val datas2 = con.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
                val datas = url.openStream().bufferedReader().useLines { lines ->
                    lines.reduce { accumulator, currentLine ->
                        "$accumulator$currentLine"
                    }
                }
                
           println(datas)
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                Log.d("Exception", ex.toString())
            }
        }).start()

        textBox.text = datas.toString()


    }
}
`
```

Quiero recuperar el HTML de cualquier web y poder almacenarlo en una variable string para que pueda modificar lo que necesite, he llegado al punto de que me lo imprime mediante "println" dentro del Thread, pero necesito poder manipular la variable fuera del hilo

Gracias de antemano,
Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes entender que cargar una web no es algo instantáneo y la app no va a esperar por ello. Cuando el `onCreate` termina de ejecutarse, todavía no se ha completado la descarga y por lo tanto no podrás imprimirla. Si quieres modificarla cuando inicia la app, necesariamente debes hacerlo dentro del thread. En cualquier otro momento, por ejemplo al presionar un botón, si puedes manipularla normalmente:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var html = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val textBox = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView1)
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button1)
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val url = URL("https://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html")
            html = url.openStream().bufferedReader().useLines { lines ->
                lines.reduce { accumulator, currentLine ->
                    "$accumulator\n$currentLine"
                }
            }
        }
        button.setOnClickListener {
            // puedes manipular el html aquí
            textBox.text = html
        }
    }

}
```

Por supuesto también puedes crear funciones pero igualmente debes llamarlas desde dentro del thread.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private fun loadUrl(url: String): String = URL(url).openStream().bufferedReader().useLines {
        it.reduce { accumulator, currentLine ->
            "$accumulator\n$currentLine"
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val textBox = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView1)
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val html = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                loadUrl("https://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html")
            }
            textBox.text = html
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Finalmente con las corutinas he conseguido poder manejar el string con el HTML, se nota que tienes experiencia en Kotlin, muchísimas gracias